# An algorithm in Racket which make an hash of references between lists?

Tags: algorithm, hash, scheme, racket

Let's consider this list:

```
(define parts '(("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "1")
                ("x" "y" "z" "a")
                ("q" "w" "e" "x")
                ("1" "2" "3" "4" "q")))
```

I need to make an hash where every first element is a key and its value is a list with references to this key appeared in another lists. This an example of my desired result:

```
(define desired-result '#hash(("a" . ("x"))
                              ("x" . ("q"))
                              ("q" . ("1"))
                              ("1" . ("a"))))
```

As you can see `"a"` (first in first list) is mentioned by `"x"` (`"a"` in present in second list beginning with `"x"`). `"x"` is mentioned by `"q"`, etc.

I have come up with this code to get a more complete view of the "references" thing, but it not what I need and it is also ugly (and possibly slow) see the complete code:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/list)

(define parts '(("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "1")
                ("x" "y" "z" "a")
                ("q" "w" "e" "x")
                ("1" "2" "3" "4" "q")))

(define my-hash (make-hash '()))

; This will initialize a key for every single element in parts
(for-each (λ (x)
            (hash-set! my-hash x '()))
          (remove-duplicates (flatten parts)))

(define (put x y)
  (hash-set! my-hash x y))

(define (get x)
  (hash-ref my-hash x))

(define (insert a n)
  (let ([aList (get a)]
        [nList (get n)])
    (unless (member n aList)
      (put a (append aList (list n))))
    (unless (member a nList)
      (put n (append nList (list a))))))

(define (iterate l)
  (let ([a (car l)]
        [r (cdr l)])
    (for-each (λ (n) (insert a n)) r)))

(for-each iterate parts)

my-hash
```

This will result in:

```
'#hash(("c" . ("a"))
       ("e" . ("a" "q"))
       ("2" . ("1"))
       ("a" . ("b" "c" "d" "e" "1" "x"))
       ("w" . ("q"))
       ("4" . ("1"))
       ("y" . ("x"))
       ("d" . ("a"))
       ("3" . ("1"))
       ("1" . ("a" "2" "3" "4" "q"))
       ("b" . ("a"))
       ("q" . ("w" "e" "x" "1"))
       ("x" . ("y" "z" "a" "q"))
       ("z" . ("x")))
```

There are surely better ways to obtain this (and I am curious if someone can suggest some) and I know I can get to `desired-result` from this, but this will be even uglier.

PS:

- This is not a school assignment
- I know hashes are not ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution additionally uses hash set for performance to test if an element is a member of the leading elements or not.

```
(define (process parts)
  (define leading-list (map first parts))
  (define leading-set (list->set leading-list))
  (define in-leading-set? (curry set-member? leading-set))
  (define my-hash (make-hash (map (curryr cons empty) leading-list)))
  (for-each
   (λ (lst)
     (for-each
      (λ (e)
        (hash-set! my-hash e (cons (first lst) (hash-ref my-hash e))))
      (filter in-leading-set? (rest lst))))
   parts)
  my-hash)
```

Here's the output

```
> (process parts)
'#hash(("1" . ("a")) ("x" . ("q")) ("q" . ("1")) ("a" . ("x")))
```

This has a caveat that, there might be some elements mapping to an empty list. For example:

```
> (define parts2 '(("a" "b")))
> (process parts2)
'#hash(("a" . ()))
```

If you don't prefer them, you could post-process by filtering them out.

Comment: It may be Racket is optimized for lists (?) or the use of sets (I am really asking here), but from my benchmarks (100000 reps) this result from 2 to 3 times slower than Michael Vehrs solution. Intuitively this should be faster... With a bigger `parts` list this can be different, I have to try

Comment: Hash table has theoretical performance of constant time for accessing / modifying, but there is an overhead for allocating the table, etc. I think the hash table will outperform the list one when the input is really big (because iterating on list takes linear time, which is bad on large input). Anyway, since you ask for a hash table solution, I give you one.

Comment: I can confirm (benchmarks made) the bigger the input the faster your algorithm. Please take no offense, I was not criticizing, only analyzing, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: Didn't feel offended! And it's good that this can help you :D

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be what you want:

```
(define dwim
  (lambda (parts)
    (let loop ((todo parts)
               (done '())
               (result '()))
      (if (null? todo)
          result
          (let* ((key (caar todo))
                 (value
                  (fold
                   (lambda (lst previous)
                     (if (member key lst)
                         (cons (car lst) previous)
                         previous))
                   '()
                   (append (cdr todo) done))))
            (loop (cdr todo)
                  (cons (car todo) done)
                  (cons (cons key value) result)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not sure I get it entirely, it outsmart me :D